# How to Get Rid of Root View Scrollbar

Tags: scrollbar, sapui5

I'm getting two scrollbars on my page. I'm using `sap.m.App` and then `sap.m.Page`. I want to disable scrolling on my `App`. I tried searching online but couldn't find anything relevant.

[image: Two scrollbars in SAPUI5]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please share with us some of your code so that we can reproduce the behavior? Please, edit your question accordingly instead of sharing it in the comment section. Right now, I'd assume that the scrollbar (2) goes away when the root view (view containing the `App` control) has the properties `height="100%"` and `displayBlock="true"` added. Please, let us know if it does.

Comment: @boghyon : Thanks man , i used height="100%" and displayBlock="true" , It's working fine now.

Comment: Please consider accepting the below answer to indicate that the issue is resolved with that solution.

Answer (score 3):

The scrollbar (2) goes away if the root view (the view containing the `<App>` control) has the properties `height="100%"` and `displayBlock="true"` added.

> Set (`displayBlock`) to `true` if the default display "inline-block" causes a vertical scrollbar with Views that are set to 100% height. [(Source)](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.View#methods/setDisplayBlock)

For example, in manifest.json:

```json
{
  "sap.ui5": {
    "rootView": {
      "...": "...",
      "height": "100%",
      "displayBlock": true,
      "async": true
    }
  }
}
```

Or in the view definition itself:

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" height="100%" displayBlock="true">
  <App xmlns="sap.m"> <!-- root view -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `enableScrolling="false"` attribute to the `<Page>` controls in your views:

```
<Page
  id="myPage"
  enableScrolling="false"
>
```